# Make Pastebin posts viewable only by people with the link, not findable in Google search results

Tags: pastebin

How can I prevent my Pastebin posts from showing up when other users search for it on things like Google?

I want to put all my assignments in links and post them on a website portfolio but I don't want to if every single person will see it if they try to Google the keywords in it.

Is there a way to post pastes that would not be easily viewed, like a private option, or where you need a direct link to view the contents, not necessarily requiring a password to view?

Or is there an alternative to Pastebin that has a private option that blocks search engines from viewing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your pastes turning up in searches then you may want to just sign up for an account, [which will allow you](http://pastebin.com/faq#11a):

> Free members can create unlimited 'public' pastes, 25 'unlisted' pastes, 10 'private' pastes.

If you need more than 10 private pastes, you can look into something like GitHub Gists which doesn't have a limit on [how many you can create](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists).

> Gists don't count against the number of private repositories for an account. There's no limit on the number of gists that can be created by a user, including users with free accounts.

Also with GitHub Gists, if you initially created a public gist, but then [later want to make it private, you can](https://github.com/blog/1837-change-the-visibility-of-your-gists).

Keep in mind that by "private" they mean unlisted, where you just need the URL to access. But otherwise it will not be searchable.

> Secret gists are the same as public gists, only they don't show up in Discover and they're not searchable. [...] Keep in mind that secret gists aren't private. If you send the URL of a secret gist to a friend, they'll be able to see it, which makes them great for quick collaboration. However, if someone you don't know discovers the URL, they'll also be able to see it.

You can embed private GitHub Gists like you can public ones.